# How to convert old project to use ARC?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have old project that uses manual memory management. My new projects are using ARC. How can I convert my old project to use ARC as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track: Your new project uses ARC (automatic reference counting). There is a lot of information available on Stackoverflow and other sites on how you can migrate to ARC.

However, you can also tell Xcode to not use ARC for individual files. Just add the `-fno-objc-arc` flag in Build Phases - Compile Sources. (There, you can add a flag to a file by double-clicking the file.)